# Generate 5 random digit number using Javascript in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I'm using `if (this.getField("Form No").valueAsString=="") {

    this.getField("Form No").value = util.printf("%05d", Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999) + 1000));

}`

In an attempt to fill a text field with a random 5 digit number in a PDF upon open. It seems to generate a number ranging from 5-6 digits instead of exactly 5.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the reples. I'm sorry but I'm very inexperienced when it comes to javascript. I assume you mean:

`function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) { return Math.random() * (max - min) + min; }`

But how would I actually put this in my own code with the 10000 as min and 99999 as max?

Comment: You're adding 1000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: Use the algorithm in duplicate question, with `10000` as the minimum, and `99999` as the maximum. If you're okay with leading zeros, use `0` as the minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry but I'm very inexperienced when it comes to javascript.

I assume you mean: 

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

But how would I actually put this in my own code with the 10000 as min and 99999 as max?

Comment: *"But how would I actually put this in my own code"* - Just define that `getRandomArbitrary()` function and call it with those values: `getRandomArbitrary(10000, 99999)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `rnd() * 99999` will give you a number in the range `0..99999` (all ranges here are inclusive at the lower end and *exclusive* at the upper, so this range does *not* include `99999`). When you add `1000` to that you'll get a number in the range `1000..100999`.

That's four-, five-, or six-digits, though you'll never see four-digit ones since you print them with `%05d` forcing a leading zero. However, the `%05d` specifies a *minimum* field width so will pass six-digit numbers through unchanged hence why you see five- and six-digit ones.

If you're after a five digit number *without* leading zeroes, you should instead be getting a number in the range 0..90000`then adding ten thousand to translate that to`10000..100000`, something like:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000
```

Or, using a generalised function:

```
function getRangeVal(lo, hi) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (hi + 1 - lo)) + lo;
}
val = getRangeVal(10000, 99999);
```

This latter method has the advantage of being able to generate numbers from an arbitrary range without having to think too much. For example, it will also easily do a five-digit number from `0..100000` with:

```
val = getRangeVal(0, 100000);
```

if that's what you were after (your question is a little vague on that, since it both adds an offset as if you wanted it to start at `10000` *and* uses `%05d` as if you were allowing for numbers *below* `10000`).

So, bottom line, if you're after numbers in `10000..100000` and `0..100000 (as string padded to five characters), use respectively:

```
strVal = util.printf("%5d",getRangeVal(10000, 99999));
strVal = util.printf("%05d",getRangeVal(0, 99999));
```

Comment: Thanks mate, so using:

'Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000' should give me the desired result of a random 5 digit number?

Comment: @christo, yes, assuming your definition of "5 digit number" is the range `10000` through `99999` inclusive at both ends. However, I'd still advise using the `getRangeVal()` function so you never have to think about this again. Life's too short to be writing the same code over and over throughout your career :-)

Comment: Thank you. 90% of what you said doesn't make much sense to me, as my experience with JS is near zero. I'm not sure why I would use the `getRangeVal()` if the ` 'Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000' `works for what I'm wanting. I'm not even sure how I would add:

`strVal = util.printf("%5d",getRangeVal(10000, 99999));
strVal = util.printf("%05d",getRangeVal(0, 99999));`

To my code anyway..

I'm a total noob, but really appreciate your help!

Comment: That's okay, @christo, just use the 'bottom line' stuff at the end. In terms of how you use the `util.printf`, use it as you currently do in your question, assigning it to the `form number` field value. But, if you'd prefer to use the simple calculation rather than the function, that's fine. It will work just as well in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate a number in the range 0 to 99,999 with 5 digits, you'll need to preserve leading zeros.

Consider using *toFixed* to retain leading zeros (provided a string is OK):

```js
console.log( Math.random().toFixed(5).replace(/\d\./,'') );
```

You could also use a function to pad with a specified number of leading zeros, but that seems a bit more complex than is required.

However, if you want numbers in the range 10,000 to 99,9999 paxdiablo has the answer.